# Special Character: "^@" before EOF

Tags: vim, character

I piped a program's output on the command line into a file and opened it in vim. At the very end of the file is the character: "^@", what does this mean?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out that it is the result of printing 256 as an ASCII character.

Comment: 256 is not representable as a one-byte character (it's 0x0100, or 0x0001, depending on byte order).  Strictly speaking, nothing above 127 is valid ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>CRTL-@</kbd> (shown by Vim as `^@`) is a `NUL` character, code point zero in the ASCII table.

You can enter it into Vim while in insert mode with <kbd>CTRL-v</kbd><kbd>CTRL-@</kbd>, or by using a tool capable of producing a `NUL` output:

```
$ printf "\0" >tempfile
```

and then check it with any hex dump program:

```
$ od -xcb tempfile
0000000    0000
         \0
        000
0000001
```

So, obviously, your program is outputting `NUL` at the end for some reason.